# Expandable UICollectionViewCell re-positioning problem

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a uicollectionview with expandable uicollectionviewcells.
At iPhone, every row has 1 column, there is no problem.
But at iPad, row has 2 column and there is a problem after expanded cell.

Here is the cells screen shot.
[not expanded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKo47.png)

[expanded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJKGq.png)

I am reloading items when arrow button clicked

```
self.collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])
```

sizeforitem func

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let height = store.pickList[indexPath.row].expanded ? CGFloat(414) : CGFloat(168)
    var width = CGFloat(0)

    if Constants.isPad { width = (self.view.frame.size.width - 25 - 12 - 12) / 2 }
    else { width = self.view.frame.size.width - 12 - 12 }

    return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
}
```

CellforRowAt:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "detailCell", for: indexPath) as! DetailCollectionViewCell


    .....
    if data.expanded {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
            cell.bottomView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 372, width: cell.frame.width, height: 42)
            cell.expandArrow.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "ok2"), for: .normal)
        }, completion: { result in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
                cell.detailView.alpha = 1
            })
        })
    }
    else {
                    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
            cell.detailView.alpha = 0
        }, completion: { result in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
                cell.expandArrow.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "ok"), for: .normal)
                cell.bottomView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 124, width: cell.frame.width, height: 42)
            })
        })
    }

    return cell
}
```

When i expand cell, row expanding also.
What is wrong with my implementation?
Thanks

Comment: Can you please attach the screenshots of the screen on iPhone, the look of which would have to be mimicked in iPad?

Comment: I cant reach web api's now. It's seeming row by row and each row has 1 column at iPhone. The row expanding when button clicked

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you seem to be using `(self.view.frame.size.width - 25 - 12 - 12) / 2` as the width of the cell when it's being displayed on an iPad.

The division of the calculated value by 2 only for iPad gives the UICollectionView enough space to display more than 1 cell in the same row. In the case of other devices, you don't have this division by 2, which allows only 1 cell to be displayed in a row.

Hence, you would have to either update your calculation to remove the division by 2, or, if the case if such that, for iPad, you need the cell to be only half of your calculated value, implement the [minimumInterItemSpacing](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewflowlayout/1617706-minimuminteritemspacing) delegate method:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    if Constants.isPad {
        // Replace this with whatever that suits your need.
        return 70.0
    } else {
        // Replace this with whatever that suits your need.
        return 10.0
    }
}
```

This would provide the two consecutive items enough space for only 1 item to be displayed in a row. You can tinker with the above values to make the cells appear the way you would like to.

Comment: If i remove sizeForItemAt method, how could i adjust cell height? Cell height is dynamically changing according to the cell expand

Comment: You don't need to remove the **sizeForItemAt** method. You just have to add in this new **minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt** method along with your previous methods to adjust the "spacing" between items.

Comment: I added minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt. And i removed "/2" from width calculation. But this time, iPad has 1 column in a row. I want to display 2 column in a row at iPad.